# How to decode the wrong encoded "b'\\xc3\\xb1'" from Django CharField

Tags: python, django, utf-8, decode, encode

I need to decode the values of Django CharField.
The values were encoded with 'text'.encode('utf-8') before store them into the database.
In the Django views, I get "b'text'" str objects from models and I can decode the text correctly.

Comment: Why are you encoding them yourself in the first place? Looks like Django is expecting `str`, not `bytes` (and presumably encoding it to whatever the DB is configured to use).

Comment: I got the DB with this encoding for some CharFields of the model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [codecs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html) package

```
import codecs
s = model_obj.char_field
codecs.escape_decode(str(s))[0].decode()[2:-1]
```